# Set Focus for ItemTemplate textbox in grid view for asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one query which is related to get focus in itemfield of Textbox in gridview. Based on checkbox selection populating different number of textBoxes and after entered data in last textbox and making webservice call based on response populating gridview with itemField(textboxes).

The scenario is explaining below.

CheckBox(Unchecked): False
Number of text boxes(ID): 1

CheckBox(Checked): True
Number of text boxes(ID, AccNo, Price): 3

After entered values in last textboxes, make webservice call and filling gridview with data but it's not get focus of first textbox in GridView.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <HeaderTemplate>
       <p>Paid Amount</p>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmnt" runat="server" TabIndex="1"
                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)" onblur="calAmount(event,this)" Text='<%# Eval("PaidAmount") %>'> 
          </asp:TextBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

I have not any event related gridview making like, rowBound, CommandView. Could you please show me a way related this.

Thank you so much in advance.